# Dynamically created button calling function dependent on variable not working

Tags: python, tkinter, dynamic

```
for x in range(NumberofStats):
        d = {}
        d["Stat{0}".format(x)] = tkinter.Button(root,text=Stats[x][0],width = Width,command = lambda: PickStat(x))
        print(x)
        d["Stat{0}".format(x)].place(relx = 0.01 + (Room*CounterStats),rely = 0.37 + CounterStats2 * 0.05)

        CounterStats += 1

        if CounterStats > 2:
            CounterStats = 0
            CounterStats2 += 1
```

Whenever I use a button it referes to the variable and but I want it do refere to what the variable was at the time it was created.
So if Stat1 is pressed it should call PickStat(1) and not PickStat(x)

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called *late binding* for lambda functions in python. Long story short, you'll need to replace `command = lambda: PickStat(x)` with `command = lambda x=x: PickStat(x)`.

Comment: thx I thought there would be an easy solution but couldnt find it